# Build QR code that provides Wifi password and then open a link

Tags: python, wifi, project, qr-code

I'm thinking of creating a python program that will help create a QR code for the WiFi password. And after connecting to Wifi it should provide a link to other services as well.

Here I want to create QR having 2 capabilities:

1. contain wifi ssid & password
2. space for other link

Comment: There are multiple project on pip([This](https://pypi.org/project/wifi-qrcode-generator/) for example) that can generate those QR codes for you.
And for the second part of your question we would need to know what exactly you have in mind.  

What have you tried already?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want a link to my website in the same qr that has password for the wifi.

Comment: To my knowledge a QR does not support both a link and a wifi login.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import module
import wifi_qrcode_generator as qr
 
# Use wifi_qrcode() to create a QR image
qr.wifi_qrcode('wifi Name ', False, 'WPA', 'password')
```

Comment: Please look over the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code snippets are much more helpful when accompanied by an explanation. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked.